# AngularJS: Adding dependencies (Inline Array vs Injection)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, dependency-injection

So I have found a practice Spring Boot project on GitHub (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot). The App allows user to create a list of items along with their descriptions; there is functionality to delete items on the list as well.  The project was an attempt to expose myself to SPA (Single Page Applications) using AngularJS.

The code adds dependencies to the defined controllers and factories using injection. Here's an example class called "controller.js" which uses this implementation:

```
var AppController = function($scope, Item) {
    Item.query(function(response) {
      $scope.items = response ? response : [];
    });

    $scope.addItem = function(description) {
      new Item({
        description: description,
        checked: false
      }).$save(function(item) {
        $scope.items.push(item);
      });
      $scope.newItem = "";
    };

    $scope.updateItem = function(item) {
      item.$update();
    };

    $scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
      item.$remove(function() {
        $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
      });
    };
  };

  AppController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Item'];
  angular.module("myApp.controllers").controller("AppController", AppController);
```

Now (correct me if I am wrong) there are two other ways to add dependencies to controllers and factories:

1. Inline Array
2. Implicit Injection

My perspective would be that I can take an application with all of its dependencies injected and rewrite the code where the controller and factory definitions would have its dependencies added using Inline Array methodology.  Here is the same "controller.js" but using Inline Array:

```
angular.module("myApp.controllerModule").controller("AppController", ['$scope', 'Item', function($scope, Item){
Item.query(function(response) {
    $scope.items = response ? response : [];
});

$scope.addItem = function(description) {
    new Item({
        description: description,
        checked: false
    }).$save(function(item) {
        $scope.items.push(item);
    });
    $scope.newItem = "";
};

$scope.updateItem = function(item) {
    item.$update();
};

$scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
    item.$remove(function() {
        $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
    });
}; }]);
```

When I tried to do so, my code does not work like the original code.  I do not know if it is a syntax error, or if there is some important difference in the application of the different styles.  Can anyone tell me why this is not working?

Comment: It would be helpful if you define `my code does not work like the original code`.

Comment: There are three ways to inject dependencies: Inline Array Annotation, `$inject` Property Annotation, and Implicit Annotation. The first two are minification safe. The last one is not. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I can see on the two code samples is the name of the Module. Since you do not provide your error Message, I assume that you have not changed `myApp.controllers` to `myApp.controllerModule` in all the files where the module should get injected.

Answer (score 0):

You can auto-generate these annotations from arguments names with [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate).  This is what most  projects should use.  Duplicating dependencies manually is not very practical.

Comment: Is that so?? I've used the `$inject` notation with minified code and it works like charm. Are you referring to any special minifying process?

Comment: You're right.  Both ways work but ng-annotate is still recommended.  Corrected the answer.